# Empty table while creating table

Tags: sql, sql-insert

My table is empty after executing.
I don't know why.

```
DROP TABLE N;
CREATE TABLE N(
BOOKNO int,
TITLE varchar(255),
PUBLICATION varchar(255),
 AUTHOR varchar(100),
PRICE decimal(6,2),
QUANTITY int,
EDITION int 
);
SELECT* FROM N;

INSERT INTO N VALUES(1,'Funda of Database system','Pearson','Elmasri, Navathe',800,25,7);
```

Comment: Move the select query to the end

`DROP TABLE N; CREATE TABLE N( BOOKNO int, TITLE varchar(255), PUBLICATION varchar(255), AUTHOR varchar(100), PRICE decimal(6,2), QUANTITY int, EDITION int ); 

INSERT INTO N VALUES(1,'Funda of Database system','Pearson','Elmasri, Navathe',800,25,7);

SELECT* FROM N;`

Comment: You select before you insert.

Answer (score 0):

You have put the select query before the Insert query

```
DROP TABLE N;
CREATE TABLE N(
BOOKNO int,
TITLE varchar(255),
PUBLICATION varchar(255),
 AUTHOR varchar(100),
PRICE decimal(6,2),
QUANTITY int,
EDITION int 
);

INSERT INTO N VALUES(1,'Funda of Database system','Pearson','Elmasri, Navathe',800,25,7);
SELECT* FROM N;
```

Answer (score 0):

It will work, try to follow below steps.

**Step-1:**

Drop Table with below query,

```
DROP TABLE N;
```

**Step-2:**

Create new table.

```
CREATE TABLE N(
BOOKNO int,
TITLE varchar(255),
PUBLICATION varchar(255),
 AUTHOR varchar(100),
PRICE decimal(6,2),
QUANTITY int,
EDITION int 
);
```

**Step-3:**

Then run insert

```
INSERT INTO N VALUES(1,'Funda of Database system','Pearson','Elmasri, Navathe',800,25,7);
```

**Step-4**

and final check data inside table with select command.`SELECT* FROM N;`